# datastore doesn't put nested struct in Go

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore

The structs look like this:

```
type Account struct {
  Username         string    // NameKey
  Password         []byte    `datastore:",noindex"`
  RegistrationTime time.Time `datastore:",noindex"`
  AppUser
}

type AppUser struct {
  LoginEntries []LoginEntry `datastore:",noindex"`
}

type LoginEntry struct {
  Timestamp time.Time `datastore:",noindex"`
  UserAgent string    `datastore:",noindex"`
  IP        string    `datastore:",noindex"`
}
```

I'm also sure I put the data correctly, because other data has no problem being updated, and I tried to `fmt.Println` the content of `account Account` right before saving it in datastore (`Put(ctx, key, &account`) and when I print it then I can see all the `AppUser` information.. but when I later `Get` the user then the `AppUser` info doesn't exist (just shows up as `{[]}`).

I'm quite certain I have stored nested struct slices before in datastore without any problems, so I'm quite confused as to what might be causing it..

---

The Put func:

```
func PutAccount(ctx context.Context, acc Account) (*datastore.Key, error) {
  if isValidUsername(acc.Username) != true {
    return nil, errors.New("Invalid username.")
  }
  var hashedPassword []byte
  if acc.RegistrationTime.IsZero() {
    var err error
    hashedPassword, err = bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(acc.Password, 12)
    if err != nil {
      return nil, err
    }
  } else {
    hashedPassword = acc.Password
  }
  account := Account{
    Username:         strings.ToLower(acc.Username),
    Password:         hashedPassword,
    RegistrationTime: time.Now(),
    AppUser:          acc.AppUser}
  fmt.Println("PutAccount, account:", account) // before saving it prints the AppUser without problems
  key := datastore.NameKey("Account", account.Username, nil)
  return database.DatastoreClient().Put(ctx, key, &account)
}
```

the Get func:

```
func GetAccount(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key) (Account, error) {
  var account Account
  err := database.DatastoreClient().Get(ctx, key, &account)
  if err != nil {
    return account, err
  }
  return account, nil
}
```

Comment: Please show the code used to get and put your data. You may also want to try a flat struct for your `Get` to see if that works.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308530/nested-structs-on-gae-datastore-using-go?rq=1

Comment: @Marc please see edit. I also noticed that answer but I found the documentation to be quite confusing and complex

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Could you try the `Get` with a flattened struct? (no embedded `AppUser`).  If that still returns no data, try the same for the Put.

Comment: @Marc Get already returns the Account struct containing all the other data (Username, Password, RegistrationTime) and this works fine, but the `AppUser` is returned as `{[]}` even though the data is visible before I Put it (tested with `fmt.Println("PutAccount, account:", account)`)

Comment: My point was that you need to figure out where this is going wrong. Is it the put or the get? You can narrow down the problem by moving to a flat struct, one where `LoginEntries` is a field of `Account`. Using other tools to check that the data is actually there would help too.

Comment: @Marc Ahh I understand now.. It works if I replace `AppUser` with `LoginEntries` as you suggested :).. but I would really like to have, e.g. `AppAuser`, `AppBUser`, etc. that each have their own `LoginEntries` among other info, do you know if it's possible to achieve this?

Comment: @Marc Hmm.. I just tried to change `AppUser` to `AppUser AppUser` and then it works.. no idea why.. I really appreciate your help <3.. I'd like to give you credit for solving the question (and get it marked as solved), but I think it's only possible if you put one of your comments as answer (:

Comment: Embedded structs are flattened out. For details see: [Datastore: Structured Properties](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#hdr-Structured_Properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using named struct works. eg:

```
type Account struct {
  Username         string    // NameKey
  Password         []byte    `datastore:",noindex"`
  RegistrationTime time.Time `datastore:",noindex"`
  AppUser          AppUser
}
```

As to why anonymous embedded struct do not, this is probably worthy of an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/issues/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it <3

Comment: It's not really "embedded" if it's named, now is it? ;)