# How do you persist and search for an entity which has multiple email addresses?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

The following code fails, because the email field is actually a list, I am wondering what the correct/efficient/idiomatic way to handle this in app engine?

```
type Person struct {
    Name    string
    Company string
    Email   []EmailAddress
}

type EmailAddress {
    Type  string // home, office, etc...
    Email string
}

var items []Person
q := datastore.NewQuery("Person").Filter("Company =", company).Filter("Email = ", email).Limit(1)
_, err := a.client.GetAll(a.ctx, q, &items)
```

It fails with the following message, which I assume is due to the fact that the email field is a 'set' of sorts:

```
datastore: bad query filter value type: invalid Value type func() string
```

Am I going to have to do something like split up the email address field, i.e:

```
type Person struct {
    Name         string
    Company      string
    EmailType    []string // home, office
    EmailAddress []string // bob@work, bob@home
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to reference the email as an attribute of the entity's [Structured Property](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/datastore/reference#hdr-Structured_Properties) `Email`, not as a property of the `Person` entity itself.

I see Go has support for loading/saving such properties (see [Nested structs on GAE datastore using Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308530/nested-structs-on-gae-datastore-using-go)), and supports query filtering in the same way indicated in the Python documentation:

```
.Filter("Email.Email = ", email)
```

Comment: This solves the problem. You are right about the documentation, it doesn't appear to be in the golang docs, but we can infer it from the python docs.